# Geolocation with Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I would like to add geolocation to the mobile version of my
map located at `http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/mobile.html`.

My map loads through this JavaScript file
`http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/js/mobilemap_v3.js`.  You
will notice that line 46 of this file is -

```
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0],myOptions);
```

I have tried the Geolocation example at `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation` and the W3 HTML5 Geolocation method at `http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp`.  But my map loads through jquery and doesn’t use

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
mapOptions);
```

like all the examples.

I can get the geolocation to work if I replace the $ in line 46 with
document.getElementById but then none of my sensors/makers will
display.

Does anyone know how I could get the geolocation working with my
markers/data still loading?

Comment: It would help if we could see the actual AJAX code you are using.

Comment: CSS for the map (#map_canvas) is at 'http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/css/mobile.css'. You can view page source of mobile.html through browser.

Comment: You should post your problem code (JS, not just CSS) directly in the question, for posterity. Your external page might change at any time, and almost certainly WILL change after you receive a helpful answer.

Comment: The code is posted. map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0],myOptions); is what is loading my map right now.  But all the Geolocation examples I find use map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
mapOptions);.  So the $ (window.jQuery) is not working with the Geolocation examples becasue they use document.getElementById.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to this!  I used geolocationmarker-compiled.js (at http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/geolocationmarker/src/geolocationmarker-compiled.js?r=379) and then added

```
var GeoMarker;

GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
    GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({
    fillColor: '#808080'});

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
      map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
      alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
    });

    GeoMarker.setMap(map);
```

and it works great.  Mobile map with Geolocation working is located at http://alert.fcd.maricopa.gov/alert/Google/v3/mobile.html and the geolocation code in in the mobilemap_v3.js file if anyone is looking to do the same thing.